# Using SQLite to display repeated and new entries

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table with 5 columns, but I really need only information from two.  Here is an example of that table, though mine has 1600+ records:

```
Date   Name
2/18   Bob
2/18   Karen
2/19   Fred
2/20   Jared
2/21   Fred
2/22   Bob
2/23   Steve
2/24   Bob
2/25   Jared
```

I would like to set a date range and find which names were repeats and which were new.  For example, if I did this for 2/18-2/21 and 2/22-2/25, I would see that in 2/22-2/25 Bob and Jared were also found in the 2/18-2/21 date range and that Steve was "new."  Does anyone have any ideas on a SQLite query to accomplish this task?

Comment: Is this the date format used in your database?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation, assuming your dates are really in a reasonable format.

```
select name,
       (case when min(date> < STARTDATE then 'RETURNING'
             else 'NEW'
        end)
from table t
where date between STARTDATE and ENDDATE
group by name;
```

Comment: I should have specified that my dates are in as TEXT, rather than date.

Comment: @user3699465 . . . In that case, fix your table so the data types are stored correctly.